# Nuxt Azure SSR Deployment to IIS - Default vue page on server only

Tags: vue.js, iis, nuxt.js

I am working to deploy an SSR nuxt app through azure.

When I run `yarn build` and `yarn start` locally, it works fine.

The pipeline is correctly building and sending the files over correctly.

I am copying over the file through the pipeline, then unzipping them.

```
mkdir server-files
          cp nuxt.config.js server-files
          cp web.config server-files
          cp yarn.lock server-files
          cp package.json server-files
          cp -r static server-files
          cp -r server server-files
          cp -r plugins server-files
          cp .env server-files
          cp -r .nuxt server-files
          cp -r api server-files
```

However, when the pipeline goes through I get this default page, and "no page found" for the pages in the application:
Page:
[image: Page URL]
Index:
[image: index / url]

Here is the web config, since that seems to be the main outlier:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/ for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a Node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in Node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <iisnode node_env="development" watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Edit for added info:
I am then installing the server packages on the server. IIS is running the start command on .js update (web.config included above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to how the Nuxt was being started.

After testing by starting the way IIS does: `node server`

I realized that when I copied over `server/index.js` from here (https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5549#issuecomment-493730227), I did not correctly change the conditional.

`config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')`

Since I am using multiple environments, this needed to be changed to

`config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV.toUpperCase === 'LOCAL'`

**Hope this helps anyone who finds this**

Side note - The nuxt docs uses a newer process for server/index.js, but it wanted a `nuxt-start` install and isDev was throwing undefined.
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-azure-portal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use vue.js on IIS, I think you need to check if you have added mimeTyhpe for it.

[image]

[image]

You can also add it in your `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".vue" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't believe that's the case, as `nuxt build` is turning the relevant .vue files into .js files